# Is it possible to change the value of a column if it has more than one result (using GROUP BY)?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Is it possible to change the result only if there's more than one?

My query brings this result:

| Date | Code | Description | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01 | 1001 | Produt A | 1234 |
| 02/01 | 1001 | Produt A | 2345 |
| 03/01 | 1001 | Produt A | 3456 |

If I have only one produt, that's fine.

But if I have more than one, it shows like this:

| Date | Code | Description | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01 | 1001 | Produt A | 1234 |
| 02/01 | 1001 | Produt A | 2345 |
| 03/01 | 1001 | Produt A | 3456 |
| 01/01 | 1002 | Produt B | 4321 |
| 02/01 | 1003 | Produt B | 5432 |
| 03/01 | 1004 | Produt B | 6543 |

The question is: Is it possible to change values only if I have more than one produt in my query?

Something like this; if I have products A and B, it should show:

| Date | Code | Description | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01 | Various | Various | 5555 |
| 02/01 | Various | Various | 7777 |
| 03/01 | Various | Various | 9999 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use case expressions, looking at the count of (optionally distinct) values in each column; for example:

```
select some_date,
  case when count(distinct code) > 1
       then 'Various'
       else to_char(max(code))
  end as code,
  case when count(distinct description) > 1
       then 'Various'
       else max(description)
  end as description,
  sum(amount) as amount
from your_table
group by some_date
order by some_date;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fb4bd70b6a4b52b2ebdb4d5245ec85da)